# What certificate/key files are needed to support 2-way SSL (SSL with Client Authentication) in Java?

Tags: java, ssl

I've got an Apache server set up with 2-way SSL, and I am trying to access it via a Java application using Apache HttpClient. I was given a certificate to install in the Java keystore (crt file) which is signed by a CA trusted by the server.

My question is: Isn't the private key (the .key file) also needed in order for this to work? If the client and server are both authenticating each other, and both give the other the public key when asked, don't both send each other an encrypted message using the other's public key before the connection is established? Or am I missing something?

Comment: A certificate without its associated private key is indeed useless. The certificate contains the public key. Each party has a certificate that it presents to the other party when connecting, and then part of the exchanges are tailored in such a way that each party will be able to prove that the other party has in fact the associated private key to the (public) certificate they are showing. This is a TLS property, irrespective of what the endpoints are and how the programs are developed.

Comment: The TLS handshake is pretty well explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake. including the case of mutual authentication. It changes slightly with TLS1.3 in the amount and type of messages exchanges but the same idea persists.